# wpf grid as itemspaneltemplate gives inconsistent heights

Tags: wpf, listbox, grid, height, row

im trying to make a week scheduler

so for each day i have a listbox with a grid as its itemspaneltemplate  , and each individual session gets its row and rowspan from the database and its working very well

the problem is when i have a short appointment so the rowspan is only 2 or 3 and the content is longer, in that case the rows containing the appointment grow to accommodate the larger content

i don't want that, id rather the appointments reflect their time span even if i don't see all data

i tried many combinations of answers that i found online

heres the whole markup

```
<ListBox Name="lsbTasks" Loaded="lsbTasks_Loaded_1" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" >
                            <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                    <Grid Initialized="Grid_Initialized_1" Background="Thistle"  IsSharedSizeScope="True"/>
                                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                            <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
                                <Style>
                                    <Setter Property="Grid.Row" Value="{Binding BusyFrom,Converter={StaticResource BusyFromConverter}}" />
                                    <Setter Property="Grid.RowSpan" Value="{Binding BusyMinutes,Converter={StaticResource BusyMinutesConverter}}" />
                                    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto" />
                                </Style>
                            </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
                            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <ScrollViewer ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" ScrollViewer.IsDeferredScrollingEnabled="True">
                                        <StackPanel Background="Purple" PreviewMouseDown="DockPanel_PreviewMouseDown_1">

                                            <TextBlock TextAlignment="Center" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding SessionPlace}" Foreground="Thistle" DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" />
                                            <TextBlock  TextAlignment="Center" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding ClientName}" Foreground="White" FontWeight="Bold" DockPanel.Dock="Top" />
                                            <TextBlock  TextAlignment="Center" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding OppositionName}" Foreground="White" DockPanel.Dock="Top" />
                                            <TextBlock  TextAlignment="Center" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding SubjectName}" Foreground="Thistle" />
                                        </StackPanel>
                                    </ScrollViewer>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        </ListBox>
```

and heres the initialization code

```
Private Sub Grid_Initialized_1(sender As Grid, e As EventArgs)
    Dim mnts = MyWorkDaySpan.TotalMinutes
    For i = 1 To mnts / 10
        Dim rd = New RowDefinition With {.Height = New GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star)}
        'rd.SharedSizeGroup = "RowGroup"
        sender.RowDefinitions.Add(rd)
    Next
End Sub
```

but still the rows are uneven, as proven by the gridlines

id appreciate any help or guidance

Comment: I guess you set the Grid's RowDefinitions in `Grid_Initialized_1`. Would it be an option to set a fixed row height there?

Comment: You may also consider to set the item's `Height` proportional to its `RowSpan`.

Comment: thanks. i cant make a fixed height as its a re-sizable window. can you elaborate how to make the height proportional to the rowspan? since i don't know the rows height i cant just put rowspan*rowheight as the elements height

Comment: I guess you know the total number of rows. Then you could easily calculate the row height from the Grid's `ActualHeight`, divided by the number of rows.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is really necessary. Provided that you properly created the RowDefinitions, all rows could be evenly sized by default. How do you set the RowDefinitions?

Comment: hi. thanks again. i added the init code towards the end of the post. please advise. i appreciate.

Comment: I had expected that setting `New GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star)` would do the job, but apparently the Grid layout ignores rows that do not contain any element. I also realized (like you did) that setting the `SharedSizeGroup` won't work. I also tried binding each row's `Height` to the Grid's `ActualHeight` (with an appropriate converter), but the Grid just gets as large as it likes, even with removing the ScrollViewer from the ListBox's Template.

Comment: My suggestion would be to use a Canvas instead of a Grid, and binding the `Canvas.Top` and `Height` properties in the ListBoxItem style. You would somehow have to pass the ListBox's `ActualHeight` to the binding converters in order to calculate the property values.

Comment: Another alternative would be to write a [custom Panel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754152.aspx#Panels_custom_panel_elements) class ("CalendarPanel"), which defines two attached properties `BusyFrom` and `BusyMinutes` and arranges its child elements according to the values of these properties.

Comment: hmmm. liked the idea of the custom panel. didn't think of that. (even though ive written a couple of panels in the past). i guess ill wait on another day or two if someone else has an idea. otherwise, i guess ill accept that answer (maybe meanwhile put it as an answer) thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a different Panel, perhaps a Canvas and bind the `Canvas.Top` and `Height` properties in the ListBoxItem style.

Another alternative would be to write a [custom Panel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754152.aspx#Panels_custom_panel_elements) class ("CalendarPanel"), which defines two attached properties `BusyFrom` and `BusyMinutes` and arranges its child elements according to the values of these properties.